# Unable to delete table from sqlite database in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, sql-delete, appdelegate

I have written a delete query in method `applicationDidEnterBackground` of `AppDelegate` class. But when i stop the simulator it does not delete the database table. I want to delete the database tables when the app enters in the background or when the app terminates. Here is my `applicationDidEnterBackground` method for delete table query.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
sqlite3 *database;
NSArray *   dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString*  docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * databasePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sssw.sqlite"];
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *sqlStatement_userInfo =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE * from SHOPDATA"];

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement_userInfo UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
            NSLog(@"table deleted");

}

else
{
    NSLog(@"Unable to delete table");
}

sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

please tell me what should i do and what am i doing wrong here.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I recommend using the [correct syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html).

Comment: Have you tried with this statement : `DROP TABLE TABLENAME`?

Comment: no. I will  now try to implement it.

Comment: I tried it, but whenever i stop running the app and start running it again, it fetches the new data as well as the previously saved data. It does not delete the previous data on closing the app. Please help me. @Jigar Tarsariya

Comment: have you tried to check by putting break point that every statement getting called?

Comment: What do you want to do? If you don't want the data to be persistent, just do'nt save in a database, no?

Comment: What do you see then ? Do you see the "Unable to delete table", as in your log statement ?

Comment: Please can anyone help me. My log statement is "table deleted". I have updated my query from "DELETE FROM SHOPDATA" to "DROP TABLE SHOPDATA". But the table is still present. What should i do?

Comment: @FredericP - I want the data to be persistent, but when i login back into my app the previous data should get vanished and new data should be fetched. Else i will have double data to view on my view controllers.That is why i want to clear the database at some points.